# Best option for online photo gallery used by iPhone app

Tags: iphone, photo-gallery

I am going to make an iPhone and Android application.
The application requires a couple of photos uploaded.

Could you please suggest me that are there any services in which I can upload photographs and can get their URL and photographs from webservice or xml in iPhone?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you're trying to do, but I think flickr, facebook, etc. have this kind of functionality.